# Static and Dynamic Behaviour of an NTC Circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis

For static and dynamic behavior analysis:

Does this circuit have a dynamic behavior?

Or all the changes in the NTC resistance due to temperature change fall under static behavior?

Or the static behavior would only be at ambient temperature, so we have both static and dynamic analysis?

[image: NTC Circuit]

Comment: *Everything* has a dynamic behaviour. What's the question that you *mean* to ask there?

Comment: When the NTC unit has a thermal time constant (has it?) it will have a dynamic behaviour.

Comment: My question is what would be included in the static behaviour analysis and what would be in the dynamic analysis? Like for example, the change in resistance due to change in temperature, is that a dynamic or static behaviour? and if we ignore thermal time constant, do we have anymore dynamic behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Even if you analyze the circuit with an absolutely fixed thermistor pellet temperature (and therefore resistance), the circuit you show has an RC time constant when it is first powered up, and acts as a low-pass filter for changes in the supply voltage.

Like any other resistors, the thermistor and the other resistors and parasitic resistances also have at least Johnson-Nyquist noise, perhaps a lot more especially in the case of the thermistor itself- 1/f noise in particular.

If you choose to model effects resulting from changes in the temperature of the thermistor’s surroundings there is another transfer function, at the very least it could be composed of another (much longer) time constant that is very dependent on what the surrounding medium etc. is and how it is behaving (eg. still air vs. rapidly flowing water). It might be composed of multiple time constants and have nonlinear components (say due to radiation).

There is also a (small in most circuits designed to measure temperature) effect from self-heating.

In some thermistor circuits, the self heating is the primary useful characteristic (NTC current limiters and PTC self resetting fuses, for example, but there are others).

What your analysis includes is up to you - you know what you are trying to model- but obviously if you don’t include the change with temperature you won’t be able to model the basic behavior of a temperature measurement or control system, and if you don’t model the dynamic response you may miss important behavior caused by the lag(s) between “plant” temperature and electrical response in a control system or the lag between temperature changes and reading settling in a measurement system.